# Grouping files and 'splitting' by number and copying them inside folders

Tags: batch-processing

I have 5000+ files inside a directory. 
I want to manage these files 'splitting' every 500 files so first pack is copied inside *folder1*, pack2 of other 500 files is copied in *folder2* and so on.
Which **.bat** script can I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET /a destcount=0
SET /a maxcount=5
SET /a filecount=maxcount
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET /a filecount +=1
 IF !filecount! geq %maxcount% (
  SET /a filecount=0
  SET /a destcount +=1
  MD "%destdir%\folder!destcount!"
 )
 ECHO(COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\folder!destcount!\"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

`maxcount` sets the number of files to assign to a group.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

Essentially, count the number of transfers and increment the destination-directoryname each time a group is complete, using `delayedexpansion` to access the run-time values of the counters

Comment: I wrong something http://pastebin.com/HUYAaNZP I test before with echo and them replace with your indication but files are not moved inside folder. However I prefer that batch command create automatically folders for every 500 files group without that I must create one by one. Is possible?

Comment: The code appears correct. The batch should automatically create directories "C:\Users\Ufficio\Desktop\temp2\folder1" (your posted batch) or "\temp\temp2\folder1" (your comment.) "folder1" will be incremented to "folder2" etc for each 500 files copied.  I'd need to know precisely what actually happened that you didn't expect to debug. This is the reason for leaving the `echo(` in place (and possibly leaving `maxcount` at a low number) - the `copy` is simply sent to the screen so you can see whther the command is correct.

Comment: it' all ok, thanks. I have no 15 reputation so i can't to change 0 to 1, sorry